# Typecast void pointer to int and string

Tags: c, pointers

What I'm trying to do is store values in a  array of Element struczs (that has a member void* data)

```
typedef struct {
void* data
} Element;
```

I have malloc'd the array to have 3 elements

```
Element* array = malloc(3 * sizeof(Element));
```

I know you can do it like this if data is a int but how do you do it if data is void *

```
array[0].data = 65;
```

I've tried typecasting

```
((*int)(array[0].data)) = 65;
```

but I get the message expected expression before 'int'

My second question is how would I go about storing  a string in the  Element struct (I can't make another member that is a string it has to be using the void pointer)

Can I use strcopy or sscanf ?

*Sample main below in case I'm doing something wrong*

```
#include "test.h"
int main (void)
{  
    Element* array = malloc(3 * sizeof(Element));
    ((*int)(array[0].data)) = 65;
    ((*int)(array[1].data)) = 64;
    ((*int)(array[2].data)) = 66;
}
```

**EDIT**

Sorry I should have added that the data will be added using a loop (the iterations is based on user input, so arrayOfElements could have 5,8,20 ect elements), based on user3386109 answer

```
Element* arrayOfElements = malloc(3 * sizeof(Element));
arrayOfElements[0].data = malloc( sizeof(int) );
int *ptr = arrayOfElements[0].data;
*ptr = 65;
```

work perfectly but if I want to make  arrayOfElements[1].data = 67

```
Element* arrayOfElements = malloc(3 * sizeof(Element));
 arrayOfElements[1].data = malloc( sizeof(int) );
 int *ptr = arrayOfElements[1].data;
 *ptr = 76;
```

I can't reuse *ptr even if I do free(ptr) , is there anyway to do this if you don't know how many elements arrayOfElements will have?

Comment: I have to use C89 ( -ansi in gcc )

Comment: Something is fundamentally wrong with your program design. If you use `void*` for any purpose, you must have a plan for how to know what types it points to, or your program will not doing anything useful. You store misc types through a `void*` then what? How will you know what each such pointer points at?

Comment: Oh I do have a way to track what type it is, what is pictured is only a small segment. But I do understand your concerns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `malloc` in your question creates an array of three structs. Each `struct` has an uninitialized pointer called `data`. Before you use that pointer you must initialize it with another call to `malloc`.

To store an `int`:

```
array[0].data = malloc( sizeof(int) );
int *ptr = array[0].data;
*ptr = 65;
```

To store a string:

```
array[0].data = malloc( strlen(str) + 1 );
strcpy( array[0].data, str );
```

---

Here's a complete example that shows how to initialize the array, print the elements of the array, and then `free` the array. Note that `ptr` is just a temporary variable that's used to avoid the nasty syntax associated with casting and dereferencing a `void *`. (A good compiler will optimize out the `ptr` variable.)

```
int main( void )
{
    int *ptr;
    char *str = "hello";

    Element *array = malloc(3 * sizeof(Element) );

    array[0].data = malloc( sizeof(int) );
    ptr = array[0].data;
    *ptr = 65;

    array[1].data = malloc( strlen(str) +  1 );
    strcpy( array[1].data, str );

    array[2].data = malloc( sizeof(int) );
    ptr = array[2].data;
    *ptr = 76;

    ptr = array[0].data;
    printf( "%d\n", *ptr );
    str = array[1].data;
    printf( "%s\n", str );
    ptr = array[2].data;
    printf( "%d\n", *ptr );

    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        free( array[i].data );
    free( array );
}
```

Comment: "Before you use that pointer you must initialize it with another call to malloc" Is that the case because data is a void* or is that in general what I have to do?

Comment: It's in general. Pointers cannot be used until they've been initialized to point to something. There are other ways to initialize a pointer, but for your example, using `malloc` is the right choice.

Comment: createArrayArray.c:26:5: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]printf( "%s\n", *str );

When I run it , it prints 65 but the I get a seg fault

Comment: @CrispyCashew Yup, already fixed, `*str` should be `str` in that `printf`. Copy/paste error.

Comment: @CrispyCashew Any time, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are in a corner case here. C standard (draft n1256) specifies in 6.3 Conversions:

> 2 Conversion of an operand value to a compatible type causes no change to the value or the
>   representation

And later in 6.3.2.3 Pointers:

> 5 An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.56)
>
> 6 Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>   the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type.

The standard library defines even a special integer type `intptr_t` that can accept without loss any pointer, but this is only an *informative* part.

Anyway, in all common implementations, it is safe to cast an integer to a pointer back and forth provided :

- if it was originally an integer, you never try to reference it, but convert it back to an integer (same type as original) before using it. As the cast shall not have changed the representation you get back the original value
- if it was originally a pointer, you do not try to use it as an integer, unless your implementation ensures that there are no trap representation - common implementations allows it
- the integer type accepts all pointer representations - if unsure use `intptr_t`

So you can do:

```
array[0].data = (void *) (intptr_t) 65;
```

and later

```
int i = (intptr_t) array[0].data;
```